# MVVM - response List does not contain any values

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit

I'm just trying to learn mvvm, and I faced some issue - My List which should contain response from API are empty. I'm not sure why it is. Here's some code:

**MainActivity**

```
mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Model>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<Model> list) {
        if (data.size() > 0) {
            data.clear();
        }
        if (list != null) {
            data.addAll(list);
            Log.i(TAG, "onChanged: " + data.size());
        }
    }
});
```

**ViewModel**

```
private Repository mRepository;
private MutableLiveData<List<Model> liveData;

public ViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    mRepository = Repository.getInstance();
    liveData = mRepository.getData();
}

public MutableLiveData<List<Model> getData(){
    return liveData;
}
```

**Repository**

```
 public MutableLiveData<List<Model>> getData(){

    MutableLiveData<List<Model> mLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    mApiCall.callApi()
            .enqueue(new Callback<List<Model>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Model> call, Response<List<Model> response) {
                    mLiveData.setValue(response.body());
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Model> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.getMessage();
                }
            });
    return mLiveData;
}
```

Comment: `response.body()` could return empty list. Have you verified that the response list is not empty?

Comment: I think you're trying to observe MutableLiveData, where you should be observing LiveData.

Comment: Well, I think so. I'm using the HttpLoggerInterceptor, and from logs I can see that everything is ok, I mean whole connection is ok. I've also tried to return some log whenever LiveList will be empty, and I did not receive any, so I think the response it's not null/empty

Comment: I would venture to say that MutableLiveData is ok. I've used in on similar project, and everything was fine.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your post. If you don't want it you can delete it instead

Answer (score 0):

in function getData() you are returning a live data and in this line in your view model :

```
liveData = mRepository.getData();
```

you are assigning it to liveDate which is a mutable live data created in your view model and the problem is here.
when this assignment is happened the observer in the liveData variable in view model will be removed and that's why we should use switchMap like this :

```
private var result : LiveData<List<Response>> = MutableLiveData()
    result : LiveData<Response> = Transformations.map(mRepository.getData()){
     it
}
```

and now all you need to do is to observe on repo in your view like this :

```
viewmodel.result.observe(this, Observer{ list ->
// to do with the result
})
```

Answer (score -1):

1. `response.body()` will provide with class APIResponse. But what you need as response is List.
   To get the expected response as List, try `response.body().getMetadata().getResults()`
2. It could be either repository initialisation as well. Do try creating

   ```
    public void init() {
        mRepository = Repository.getInstance();
        liveData = mRepository.getData();
    }
   ```

use `viewModel.init();`

3. Model class properties should match with response JSON fields to get the model objects from the response.

Debug on the response.body() and see the data coming. if the model is empty then there would be a mismatch on the fields.